# How to get last value from throttled function

Tags: javascript, lodash

The documentation for the [_.throttle](https://lodash.com/docs#throttle) function states that:

> Creates a throttled function that only invokes func at most once per
>   every wait milliseconds. The throttled function comes with a cancel
>   method to cancel delayed func invocations and a flush method to
>   immediately invoke them. Provide an options object to indicate whether
>   func should be invoked on the leading and/or trailing edge of the wait
>   timeout. The func is invoked with the last arguments provided to the
>   throttled function. Subsequent calls to the throttled function return
>   the result of the last func invocation

I'm interested in this line:

> Subsequent calls to the throttled function return
>   the result of the last func invocation

I've tried:

```
var throttled = _.throttle(updateModelData, 1000);
service.on('change', function () {
    throttled(5);
});

function updateModelData(data) {
    // all calls here log 5's
    console.log(data);
    return data;
}

setTimeout(function() {
    throttled(); // here updateModelData is executed with `undefined` value
}, 5000);
```

The problem is that `throttled()` triggers function without returning the data. How can I invoke it so that it returns last data?

EDIT:

According to source code, the value will be returned only if no pending function call exists `isCalled === false`:

```
  function debounced() {
    args = arguments;
    stamp = now();
    thisArg = this;
    trailingCall = trailing && (timeoutId || !leading);

    if (maxWait === false) {
      var leadingCall = leading && !timeoutId;
    } else {
      if (!maxTimeoutId && !leading) {
        lastCalled = stamp;
      }
      var remaining = maxWait - (stamp - lastCalled),
          isCalled = remaining <= 0 || remaining > maxWait;

      !!!!! HERE
      if (isCalled) {
        if (maxTimeoutId) {
          maxTimeoutId = clearTimeout(maxTimeoutId);
        }
        lastCalled = stamp;
        result = func.apply(thisArg, args);
      }
      else if (!maxTimeoutId) {
        maxTimeoutId = setTimeout(maxDelayed, remaining);
      }
    }
    ...
    return result;
  }
```

So the following will work:

```
var throttled = _.throttle(updateModelData, 10000);
service.on('change', function () {
    throttled(5);
});

function updateModelData(data) {
    // all calls here log 5's
    console.log(data);
    return data;
}

setTimeout(function() {
    throttled(); // returns 5
}, 15000);
```

Comment: What is `this.getData`?

Comment: @elclanrs, I've removed `this.getData()` from the example, it should be clear now, take a look please

Comment: @Maximus where do you save the value returned from the throttled function?

Comment: @Neal, I don't, the value is stored within `debounce` function of lodash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that, when you have leading invocations (the default behavior for `_.throttle`), when you first call the throttled function (or first call it after after your delay time has passed) it immediately calls the underlying function, before returning anything.

That means that the "result of the last function invocation" might be the result of a function invocation that was caused by your *current* call to the throttled function.  So your call to `throttle()` calls `updateModelData()` and then returns undefined, since `updateModelData()` returns undefined.

Here's some sample code that might clarify this:

```
var foo = (x) => x;
var leading = _.throttle(foo, DELAY, {leading: true, trailing: false}); //these are the default options for leading and trailing
var trailing = _.throttle(foo, DELAY, {leading: false, trailing: true});

leading(1); //Calls foo(1), returns 1
leading(2); //Doesn't call foo, returns 1, 
leading(3); //Doesn't call foo, returns 1

trailing(1); //Doesn't call foo, returns undefined
trailing(2); //Doesn't call foo, returns undefined

//DELAY ms later
//foo(2) is called, due to the most recent call to bar2

leading();  //Calls foo(), returns undefined 
leading(1); //Still returns undefined from above

trailing(); //Doesn't call foo, returns 2
trailing(1); //Doesn't call foo, returns 2

//Another DELAY ms later

leading("Whatever"); //Calls foo("Whatever"), returns "Whatever";
```

Here's a version of your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/12heufex/7/) that makes it slightly more obvious too.

---

Really, you shouldn't call a function just to get the last value returned by it, so I'd suggest you just manage the last value yourself and not rely on `_.throttle` to do it for you. For example:

```
var lastResultOfFoo;
var foo = function (x) {
    lastResultOfFoo = x;
    return x;
}

//OR (if you don't mind attaching arbitrary properties to functions)
var foo = function (x) {
    foo.lastResult = x;
    return x;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the clear explanation, _so I'd suggest you just manage the last value yourself_ - that's what I tried to avoid, but it seems that the behavior of `_throttle` re returned value is confusing, so probably I'll stick to handling the value myself

Comment: @Maximus Depending on what you're doing, you might consider the event-emitter pattern.  That allows consuming code to just use the latest value when it's produced, or store it for later use if it needs to.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works fine:

```
var throttled = _.throttle(updateModelData, 1000);
var i = 0;

function updateModelData(data) {
    return data;
}

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    console.log(throttled(i++));

    if (i === 6) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        console.log('Last value: ' + throttled());
    }
}, 2000);
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
"Last value: 5"
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/12heufex/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: yes, that's working, but then try later get the latest value by just calling `throttled()`

Comment: yeah, thanks for you efforts, but I still can't grasp the logic behind this behavior